# How Do I Use a User-Defined Struct in a User-Defined Class in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, class, powershell, struct, add-type

I've tried this on PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0.  I'm having trouble using a structure inside a class.  I can use the properties inside a structure directly from PowerShell without issue.  I can also use any standard-type properties inside a class directly from PowerShell without issue.  However, when I combine the two (try to use a custom-type property inside a class), I can't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a quick sample code to reproduce what I'm seeing:

```
$MyTest = Add-Type @"
namespace MyTest
{
    public struct Struct1
    {
        public string Property;
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public struct Struct2
        {
            public string Property;
        }

        public string MyString;
        public Struct1 Struct1Property;
        public Struct2 Struct2Property;
    }
}
"@ -PassThru

$struct1 = New-Object -TypeName MyTest.Struct1
$class1 = New-Object -TypeName MyTest.Class1
$struct1.Property = 'test'
$struct1.Property   # Outputs: test
$class1.MyString = 'test'
$class1.MyString    # Outputs: test
$class1.Struct1Property.Property = 'test'
$class1.Struct1Property.Property    # Outputs: <nothing>
$class1.Struct2Property.Property = 'test'
$class1.Struct2Property.Property    # Outputs: <nothing>
```

I'm expecting that both $class1.Struct1Property.Property and $class1.Struct2Property.Property should output 'test'.

If I compile the same code as a Console Application with VS2013, it works just fine.

Console application code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyTest.Struct1 struct1;
            MyTest.Class1 class1 = new MyTest.Class1();

            struct1.Property = "test";
            Console.WriteLine("struct1.Property: {0}", struct1.Property);

            class1.Struct1Property.Property = "test";
            Console.WriteLine("class1.Struct1Property.Property: {0}", class1.Struct1Property.Property);

            class1.Struct2Property.Property = "test";
            Console.WriteLine("class1.Struct2Property.Property: {0}", class1.Struct2Property.Property);
        }
    }
}

namespace MyTest
{
    public struct Struct1
    {
        public string Property;
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public struct Struct2
        {
            public string Property;
        }

        public string MyString;
        public Struct1 Struct1Property;
        public Struct2 Struct2Property;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
struct1.Property: test
class1.Struct1Property.Property: test
class1.Struct2Property.Property: test
```

Comment: These are fields not properties, which makes a big difference. If they are properties, the equivalent C# code won't even compile.

Comment: Question has been answered on Technet: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0a599f45-bf05-474c-b585-8bb0e1a7fa67/how-do-i-use-a-userdefined-struct-in-a-userdefined-class?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Are you referring to my word choice of "Property"?  I stole it from the MemberType output of the Get-Member cmdlet.  Even though the word itself is arbitrary, I apologize for any confusion.  You are correct, they are indeed fields.  Regardless, it seems that PowerShell does not treat structures the same way C# does.